# Sharing webapp2 session between GAE python modules with custom domain?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I have a multi-module GAE app sharing the session info properly across modules when served via `appspot.com`. I used [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811286/how-to-share-sessions-between-modules-on-a-google-app-engine-python-application):

```
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
     cookie_args': { 
         'domain' : ".appspot.com"
}
```

But session sharing no longer works when served through my custom domain (modules are mapped to different hostnames on that domain) - understandable since that domain is not known to webapp2.

If I update the config to match my custom domain instead session sharing no longer works between modules served by .appspot.com.

Is there a way to make session sharing work on both .appspot.com **and** my custom domain?

To clarify - I'm not talking about session sharing *across* domains, only *within the same* domain.

Thanks.