# How to share sessions between modules on a Google App Engine Python application with django framework?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

Here is a similar question: [How to share sessions between modules on a Google App Engine Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811286/how-to-share-sessions-between-modules-on-a-google-app-engine-python-application)

I have two modules: default and helloworld

I want all the `myapp.appspot.com/helloworld/*` will be routed to the helloworld module.

The dispatch.yaml is as follows:

```
application: myapp
dispatch:
- url: "*/helloworld/*"
  module: helloworld
```

when I request `myapp.appspot.com/helloworld/`, it will be redirected to the login page as I use the @require_login in helloworld.urls.

helloworld.urls:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.home.as_view()), name='helloworld-home'),
)
```

However, the login_require is routed to /account/login and is processed by the default module, and the helloworld module can not share the session created by the default module.

Therefore, I will be redirected again to the login page after I login in.

Here is my wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'libs'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The possible solution with webapp2 will pass a config to the wsgi application:

```
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
     cookie_args': { 
         'domain' : "yourapp.appspot.com"
}
```

But I can not find any doc related to django :(

Is it possible to share the session between modules when using django framework in GAE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing django sessions on specific subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742675/sharing-django-sessions-on-specific-subdomains)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/ and make sure both modules are using the same session config, keys, storage, etc.