# How to share session between gcp app engine standard instance

Tags: session, google-app-engine-python

I am using GCP App Engine Standard and, for some reason, would like to let user keep login as long as they wish.
However, i encounter an issue.
If user visit the site in peak period, App Engine will create a new instance for handling requests.
If user login at peak period, App Engine will remember during operation.
But, if user come back a few days, they have to login again....

**Question:**
Is there any way to handle the session issue?
Or is there any way to handle the login issue?

P.S. It will be great if the answer can base on App Engine Standard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share sessions between modules on a Google App Engine Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811286/how-to-share-sessions-between-modules-on-a-google-app-engine-python-application)

Comment: Seem that is for session sharing between two sub domain, I am afraid it is not the same situation

Comment: Actually, I think my problem is sharing session/cookie in same domain but different instance.
Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong :-D